# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on simple alert function

Tags: javascript

I'am doing the simpliest javascript function and I still manage to get errors -.-

```
alert('Adding 'number1' with 'number2' we will get 'number1+number2);
```

Message on Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: you need to use + to concatenate strings into one string.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert('Adding ' + number1 + ' with ' + number2 + ' we will get ' + (number1+number2));
```

`alert()` accepts `string`. If you do not add parenthesis, you are basically concatenating number 1 and number 2 as string instead of doing arithmetic operation on them.

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: Okay, thank you but can you explain a little? Cause I'm confused why we need these ( )